# Google Drive SDK (Java) service account upload file and access from browser

Tags: java, google-drive-api

As I mentioned in the title, I'm uploading gzip files from my java application as below:

```
private static File insertFile( Drive service, String title, String description, String parentId, String mimeType, String filename ){
    // File's metadata.
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle( title );
    body.setDescription( description );
    body.setMimeType( mimeType );

    // Set the parent folder.
    if( parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0 ){
        body.setParents( Arrays.asList( new ParentReference().setId( parentId ) ) );
    }

    // File's content.
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File( filename );
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent( mimeType, fileContent );
    try{
        File file = service.files().insert( body, mediaContent ).execute();
        return file;
    }
    catch( IOException e ){
        System.out.println( "An error occured: " + e );
        return null;
    }
}



public static Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException{
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport( httpTransport ).setJsonFactory( jsonFactory ).setServiceAccountId( SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL )
                .setServiceAccountScopes( Arrays.asList( DriveScopes.DRIVE ) ).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File( new java.io.File( SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH ) ).build();

        Drive service = new Drive.Builder( httpTransport, jsonFactory, null ).setHttpRequestInitializer( credential ).setApplicationName( "Svn Backup" ).build();
        return service;
    }




public void main()
{
 Drive driveService = getDriveService();
                // Insert a file

                System.out.println( new LocalDateTime().toString( "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" ) + ": " + "trying to upload google drive.." );
                File file = insertFile( driveService, new LocalDateTime().toString( "dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss" ), "", null, "application/x-gzip", args[ 1 ] + ".gz" );
                System.out.println( new LocalDateTime().toString( "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" ) + ": " + "File: " + file );
                System.out.println( "successfuly uploaded" );
}
```

It works perfectly, because I can reach my files with `files().list()` command, but I can not see my files in the Google drive applications neither in the `https://drive.google.com/`

What is the reason of that? What should I do ?

Comment: It usually only takes a couple of seconds for the file to be visible in the web interface. Please check your app and web interface are looking at the same account.

Comment: its both same account... i can not see my uploaded files for days (10 days)

Comment: Does a search in the UI turn up anything?

Comment: no, i could not find it.

Comment: You said the file is returned by Files.list(). Look at the details of the File object returned and see if you can determine which folder it is in, etc.

Comment: but in Google drive GUI, there's no folder. there's nothing !

Comment: Perhaps the details returned by the API will provide some clues.